# If-else statement not working

Tags: java

I am trying to set the price depending on a randomly generated temperature. However, it only returns the first two options $0.50 and $0.55. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the && statements but I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working.

```
public static double GetPrice ()
{
    if (temp < 50)
    {
        price = 0.50;
    }
    else if (temp >= 50)
    {
        price = 0.55;
    }
    else if (temp >= 61 && temp <= 65)
    {
        price = 0.60;
    }
    else if (temp >= 66 && temp <= 70)
    {
        price = 0.65;
    }
    else if (temp >= 71 && temp <= 75)
    {
        price = 0.75;
    }
    else if (temp >= 76 && temp <= 80)
    {
        price = 0.80;
    }
    else if (temp >= 81 && temp <= 85)
    {
        price = 0.85;
    }
    else if (temp >= 86 && temp <= 90)
    {
        price = 0.90;
    }
    else if (temp > 90)
    {
        price = 1.00;
    }

    return price;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged through your code? What happened, with what input? (It's important to learn how to diagnose problems for yourself...)

Comment: Firs two conditions solves the whole range `(temp < 50)` or `(temp >= 50)` catch everything you test. There is missing something like:  `(temp >= 50 && temp <= 60)`

Comment: also your code has quite poor quality, you are always repeating the same `else if (temp >= XY && temp <= YZ)` this indicate, that something is wrong. And debugging will be harder in this type of code. What if you use something like `price = round(temp / 100)` - this will solve all you need (play with this tip, is not real working code)

Comment: you should know that if you put an   else if (temp >= 50) and the value is 65 for example will always enter on that condition, and once an IF condition was accepted, all the ELSE conditions you have wont be necessary

Comment: Remember that `else` is essentially equivalent to saying `if (previous conditions false)`. When the conditions of the if portion of your else if statement are satisfied but the code still isn't executed, then it probably means an earlier check was already satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the first two conditions to

```
if (temp >=0 && temp < 50)
    {
        price = 0.50;
    }
    else if (temp >= 50 && temp < 61)
    {
        price = 0.55;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the first two branches are true either way.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the beginning of your if-else ladder.

```
if (temp < 50)
{
    price = 0.50;
}
else if (temp >= 50)
{
    price = 0.55;
}
```

The first case covers all the scenario where temp is less than 50. The second case covers all the parts where temp is greater than or equal to 50. This covers the set of all possible values and so no other clause gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

The first else if doesn't have an upper bound for temp.
Change 
`else if (temp >= 50)`  to
`else if (temp >= 50 && temp < 61)`